# What happened in the 200 years between Oblivion and Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

Is there any information (in-game, or externally) about the significant events that transpired in the realm of Tamriel between Oblivion and Skyrim?

At the end of Oblivion, the empire's bloodline died with Martin... but now in Skyrim there's an emperor again?

What's the history with the Aldmeri Dominion?

I *did* find one in-game book about the Game's 3rd era, but it ended with The Knights of the Nine reforming (Oblivion DLC), and didn't make it up through the intervening span between the games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quick answer BUT in the Dragonsreach there is a book in the same room as the enchanting table that explains all events of Oblivion and briefly summarizes what happened in-between the games.  Including that the Septim dynasty ended at the end of the main quest for oblivion and names the new dynasty that controls the empire.

Add On:

The third era ended and the fourth era begins when you and Martin Septim defeat/banish Mehrunes Dagon.  Hit this site its a pretty good timeline for the 200 missing years including Hammerfells exit from the empire and Vvardenfell being destroyed.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Fourth_Era

Comment: That sounds promising. Do you know the name of the book, by chance?

Comment: +1. This is great as a timeline. I've used it myself and was going to suggest it until seeing TombstoneTwo's answer.

Comment: Such as the Great War, and many more!

Answer (score 0):

I am new here, so I don't know if this is proper. 
BUT
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Skyrim I  think is what you are looking for.
AND
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skyrim

That is where I got my Lore from.  Now collecting books to read later.